# Importing font family in angular 4

Tags: angular, font-family

I have written html code for an login page in (app.component.html) and it's css in (app.component.css),I want to import/use Open sans,font-family. I am bit confused by seeing different answers in various websites.Can u provide step-wise procedure to use Open sans font-family in angular 4?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## 2 Step Fix

> Step - 1 : **Insert** the link in your **index.html** page

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
```

> Step - 2 : **Use it** In your css file (Component.css)

```
* {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```